# Free MP2 Converter for Mac

Tags: radio, broadcast-standards, converter, freeware

In South Africa, the radio stations requires the sound to be an MPEG Audio Layer II with a
Constant Bitrate of 384kbit/sec. I haven't come across this before, and I'm struggling to find a free converter for Mac.

Can anyone advise?

Is this a common format for other countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg will do that for you. You can either get [FFmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) which is a GUI version of it but it runs a rather old version of FFmpeg. Or you could [use MacPorts and compile the latest version for your computer](http://www.haykranen.nl/2007/11/21/howto-install-and-use-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) and use it via the command line.

```
ffmpeg -i <your_input_file> -acodec mp2 -ab 384k <your_output_file>.mp2 #(or m2a or mpg or else)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. Going to try @sepulchra's converter, and if I don't come right then I'll do the fancy command line stuff :-) 

Comment: You're a life savor. Even though it took about an hour to install, it was totally worth it! Thanks so much. I always feel so cool using the Terminal, wish I actually knew what I was doing ;-)

Comment: Haha you're welcome, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

I know Audacity will import an MP2 but not sure if it will save out to one. Worth a try.

Music Man isn't free but almost ($25):

http://www.mireth.com/pub/mpme.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I saw the Mireth one, but would rather not pay 25$ for a once off conversion. Audacity converts from MP2 to other formats, but not the other way (unless I'm missing something). 

Answer (score 1):

You could try [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm) and run it with this program called [Darwine](http://darwine.sourceforge.net/) that lets you run windows programs or something not really sure tbh, just heard of it from MediaCoder's website haha. May be you can try any free converter for windows and see if it would run with Darwine..

Answer (score 1):

PRX is a radio org in the US and they provide a free MP2 encoder:  http://www.prx.org/tools-and-resources/prx-tools

Comment: This is a super app, but it won't let me change the settings to 48k + 384kbit/sec. This one is defaulted to 44.1 + 256. Arg, what a pity.